# Uninitialized Keyword argument leading to shared properties between instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've run into a situation wherein an unused keyword argument in a class initialization leads to unwanted sharing of properties.

The `ActionsAgent` class below has a `actions` property that is intended to hold a list of pending actions, and a `addActions` method that appends actions to that list. Its initialization allows an initial action list to be supplied with a keyword argument that defaults to `[]`.

```py
###############
# Define

class ActionsAgent(object):
  def  __init__( self, name="",actions=[]):
    self.name = name
#     self.actions = []
    self.actions = actions
    print("init {}: {}".format(self.name,self.actions))
  def addActions(self,*actions):
    print("addActions {}, enter: {}".format(self.name,self.actions))
    for action in actions:
      self.actions.append(action)
    print("addActions {}, exit: {}".format(self.name,self.actions))
```

The following test defines two agents, `alice` and `bob`, and adds two actions to each.

```py
##############
# TEST
alice = ActionsAgent(name="alice")
bob = ActionsAgent(name="bob")
alice.addActions("hop", "skip")
bob.addActions( "run", "jump" )

print("alice end actions", alice.actions)
print("bob end actions", bob.actions)
```

The expected behavior is for `alice`'s actions to be `"hop"` and `"skip`, and for `bob`'s to be `"run"` and `"jump"`. However upon running the test, it is shown that `bob` shares `alice`'s actions when running `addActions` and that upon exit both agents share the same actions.

```
init alice: []
init bob: []
addActions alice, enter: []
addActions alice, exit: ['hop', 'skip']
addActions bob, enter: ['hop', 'skip']
addActions bob, exit: ['hop', 'skip', 'run', 'jump']
alice end actions ['hop', 'skip', 'run', 'jump']
bob end actions ['hop', 'skip', 'run', 'jump']
```

Note, that if the two agents are supplied the `actions` keyword (`alice = ActionsAgent(name=`alice`,actions=[])`, then the test run's as expected. If the initialization sets actions to `[]` the test also runs as expected.

What is going on here?

Answer (score -2):

It seems that when `ActionsAgent` is initialized without the `actions` keyword, a new variable is created and assigned to `self.actions`. Since this variable is not a simple data (such as an integer or None), its reference (not value) is assigned to `self.actions`. Hence, any instances not assigned that keyword will share that same reference.

I noted in the question two ways in which I can get my expected result. A better way is to use a `None` in the initialization function:

```py
class ActionsAgent(object):
  def  __init__( self, name="",actions=None):
    self.name = name
    if actions is None:
      self.actions = []
    else:
      self.actions = actions
    print("init {}: {}".format(self.name,self.actions))
```